# Displaying video using RTC Peer Connection issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc

I am currently building an application, which establishes a rtc peer connection with the server and receives video, which is then displayed on the page. However, I currently have an issue with the video flickering for some reason.

This is my parent component, where connection is established and managed

```
const RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection.bind(window);

  const setRTCVideoRef = (stream: MediaStream) => {
    if (!stream || !rtcVideoRef.current) return;

    setIsIdleVideoPlaying(false);

    rtcVideoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
    rtcVideoRef.current
      .play()
      .then(() => {})
      .catch(() => {});
  };

  const playIdleVideo = () => {
    setIsIdleVideoPlaying(true);
  };

  const onVideoStatusChange = (isPlaying: boolean, stream: MediaStream) => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      const remoteStream = stream;
      setRTCVideoRef(remoteStream);
    } else {
      playIdleVideo();
    }
  };

  const onTrack = (event: RTCTrackEvent) => {
    if (!event.track) return;

    if (statsIntervalId.current) clearInterval(statsIntervalId.current);

    statsIntervalId.current = setInterval(async () => {
      const stats = await peerConnection?.getStats(event.track);

      stats?.forEach((report) => {
        if (report.type === 'inbound-rtp' && report.kind === 'video') {
          const videoStatusChanged = videoIsPlaying.current !== report.bytesReceived > lastBytesReceived.current;

          if (videoStatusChanged) {
            onVideoStatusChange(report.bytesReceived > lastBytesReceived.current, event.streams[0]);
          }

          videoIsPlaying.current = report.bytesReceived > lastBytesReceived.current;

          lastBytesReceived.current = report.bytesReceived;
        }
      });
    }, 100);
  };

  const closePC = () => {
    if (!peerConnection) return;

    peerConnection.close();

    peerConnection.removeEventListener('icecandidate', onIceCandidate, true);
    peerConnection.removeEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', onIceConnectionStateChange, true);
    peerConnection.removeEventListener('track', onTrack, true);

    if (statsIntervalId.current) {
      clearInterval(statsIntervalId.current);
    }

    setPeerConnection(null);
  };

  const onIceCandidate = (event: RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent) => {
    if (event.candidate && streamData) {
      const { candidate, sdpMid, sdpMLineIndex } = event.candidate;

      iceCandidate(streamData.id, streamData.session_id, candidate, sdpMid, sdpMLineIndex);
    }
  };

  const onIceConnectionStateChange = () => {
    if (
      peerConnection &&
      (peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'failed' || peerConnection.iceConnectionState === 'disconnected')
    ) {
      closePC();
      setIsPeerConnectionModalOpen(true);
    }
  };

  const initStream = async () => {
    const avatarUrl = 'image.png';
    const data = await startStream(avatarUrl);
    if (data) setStreamData(data);
  };

  const createPeerConnection = async (offer: RTCSessionDescriptionInit) => {
    if (!peerConnection) return;

    peerConnection.addEventListener('icecandidate', onIceCandidate, true);
    peerConnection.addEventListener('iceconnectionstatechange', onIceConnectionStateChange, true);
    peerConnection.addEventListener('track', onTrack, true);

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

    const sca = await peerConnection.createAnswer();

    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sca);

    setSessionClientAnswer(sca);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!sessionClientAnswer || !streamData) return;

    sdpResponse(streamData.id, streamData.session_id, sessionClientAnswer);
  }, [sessionClientAnswer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!peerConnection || !streamData) return;

    createPeerConnection(streamData.offer);
  }, [peerConnection]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!streamData) return;

    const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: streamData.ice_servers });
    setPeerConnection(pc);
  }, [streamData]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (messagesWrap.current && !isDesktop) setOffsetTop(messagesWrap.current!.offsetTop);

    playIdleVideo();
    initStream();
    onLoadComplete();

    return () => {
      if (statsIntervalId.current) clearInterval(statsIntervalId.current);

      closePC();

      useChatsStore.setState({ messages: [], next: null });
    };
  }, []);
```

And then, I pass rtcVideoRef to child component, which renders either rtc video or idle video.

```
<video
  src={IdleVideo}
  playsInline
  loop
  autoPlay
  muted
  preload="auto"
  x-webkit-airplay="allow"
  css={css.characterIdleVideo(isIdleVideoPlaying)}
/>
<video
  ref={rtcVideoRef}
  playsInline
  autoPlay
  preload="auto"
  x-webkit-airplay="allow"
  css={css.characterStreamVideo(!isIdleVideoPlaying)}
/>
```

If anyone knows what can cause the flickering effect (switching between rtc and idle video), please answer.